# How do I send flags to the erlang vm using :emu_args?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, escript

I want to send arguments to the erlang vm, but 'emu_args: "+A32"' appears after the "-escript main parallel_tree_walk_escript" and appears to become arguments for the elixir program instead of affecting the erlang VM.

Without 'emu_args: "+A32"', the file created by "mix escript.build" contains line three

```
%%! -escript main parallel_tree_walk_escript
```

I seem to get the results I want if I alter that line with emacs (copes well with the non-ascii contents) to

```
%%! +A32 -escript main parallel_tree_walk_escript
```

However, if I use 'emu_args: "+A32" in mix.esx, the line becomes

```
%%! -escript main parallel_tree_walk_escript +A32
```

...and "+A32" appears not to go to the erlang vm, but instead appear as the first command line element of the args array.

```
# permits emacs edit of parallel_tree_walk result
  def escript do
    [
      main_module: ParallelTreeWalk,
    ]
  end
```

But this apparently puts the argument in the wrong location:

```
  def escript do
    [
      main_module: ParallelTreeWalk,
      emu_args: "+A32"
    ]
  end
```

I hoped for

```
%%! +A32 -escript main parallel_tree_walk_escript
```

but the result was

```
%%! -escript main parallel_tree_walk_escript +A32
```

which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I generate an escript, and manually add the `-emu_args` flag, in the same way you moved the `+A32` flag, I get the same output whether `+A32` is before or after the escript name:

```
# %%! -emu_args -escript main test_escript +A32 
# %%! +A32 -emu_args -escript main test_escript
```

Both produce (truncated some paths for brevity):

`Executing: …beam.smp ./test -B -A32 -- -root …erlang/21.3 -progname erl -- -home /Users/adam -- -boot no_dot_erlang -noshell -escript main test_escript -run escript start -extra ./test`

Maybe you could try adding the `emu_args` parameter to see what's happening. It could be that the `+A32` flag is getting to the VM.

This is the first time I've looked at escripts, so I was curious that the argument to beam ended up as `-A32` instead of `+A32`, but that seems to be a difference between executing the emulator directly, or via a script. Calling `…beam.smp --help` does indeed list the `-A` version along with a final note that says:

> Note that if the emulator is started with erlexec (typically
>   from the erl script), these flags should be specified with +.

Comment: Well, now I don't know what to think: the "+A32" at the end of the third line which I thought was failing ("doesn't work") is working exactly as intended today, in that the argument list to main(args \\ []) are what they are supposed to be with the "./parallel_tree_walk ." invocation, and ":erlang.system_info(:thread_pool_size)" is returning 32 exactly as intended.  I don't know what happened.  Perhaps I had a typo which got removed during my various attempts.Thank you for your time.